# tikz library calc and auctex preview in emacs fails

Tags: tikz-pgf, emacs, auctex, preview

The emacs-variable preview-default-preamble contains the statement \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture} so tikz pictures are processed by preview, which usually works fine.

But preview in emacs fails if I use the calc library. Minimum example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw ($(0,0) + (0,0)$) -- ($(1,1) + (1,1)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

throws the following error in emacs

```
! Preview: Snippet 1 started.
<-><->

l.8 \begin{tikzpicture}

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pr@$ 
l.9 \draw ($(0,0)
                  + (0,0)$) -- ($(1,1) + (1,1)$);
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \pr@$ 
l.9 \draw ($(0,0)
                  + (0,0)$) -- ($(1,1) + (1,1)$);
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \pr@$ 
l.9 \draw ($(0,0)
                  + (0,0)$) -- ($(1,1) + (1,1)$);

! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `0' or `0@' (in '$(0').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9 \draw ($(0,0)
                  + (0,0)$) -- ($(1,1) + (1,1)$);
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.9 \draw ($(0,0)
                  + (0,0)$) -- ($(1,1) + (1,1)$);
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pr@$ 
l.9 \draw ($(0,0)
                  + (0,0)$) -- ($(1,1) + (1,1)$);
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \pr@$ 
l.9 \draw ($(0,0)
                  + (0,0)$) -- ($(1,1) + (1,1)$);
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \pr@$ 
l.9 \draw ($(0,0)
                  + (0,0)$) -- ($(1,1) + (1,1)$);

! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `0' or `0@' (in '$(0').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9 \draw ($(0,0)
                  + (0,0)$) -- ($(1,1) + (1,1)$);
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.9 \draw ($(0,0)
                  + (0,0)$) -- ($(1,1) + (1,1)$);

! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9 \draw ($(0,0) + (0,0)$
                          ) -- ($(1,1) + (1,1)$);
Preview: Tightpage -32891 -32891 32891 32891
! Preview: Snippet 1 ended.(26214+0x26214).
<-><->

l.10 \end{tikzpicture}
```

My emacs-version is

```
GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0, Carbon Version 1.6.0 AppKit 1265)
```

Any hints for solving this issue are appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I just found the answer to my question here on stackexchange:
resetting the $ to its original catcode seems to work (do not ask me why :-) ):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\catcode`$=3 } % $
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw ($(0,0) + (0,0)$) -- ($(1,1) + (1,1)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(I added the comment % $, so that font-locking will not be screwed in emacs)